# Exception handling Camel

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm trying to pick a file from a directory, split a file and add each splitted lines to activemq. I'm facing a problem with exception handling during this process. Lets say a file in the directory is a binary file (executable), then splitter thows org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException and java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException exceptions. If this occurs, then I need to catch these exceptions, nothing should add in activemq and that just particular thread should exit after logging exception. Referred online and wrote the following code but don't know how to stop adding to activemq and quit specific thread.

```
<route id="msg_producer">
        <from uri="input.file.from" />
        <doTry>
        <split parallelProcessing="true" executorServiceRef="msgProducer"
            streaming="true">
            <tokenize token="\n"></tokenize>
            <to uri="input.activemq.to" />
        </split>
        <doCatch>
            <exception>org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException</exception>
            <exception>java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException</exception>
                <handled> <constant>true</constant></handled>
                <setBody>
                    <simple>${exception.stacktrace}</simple>
                </setBody>
                <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
                    <simple>${file:onlyname.noext}_error.log</simple>
                </setHeader>
        </doCatch>
        </doTry>
    </route>
```

Comment: There is an stopOnException option you can use on the splitter

Comment: Though a more cleaner solution is maybe to filter the file and not try to split and send it to AMQ if its a binary file.

Comment: Thanks Claus, but filtering file would be too difficult option because directory can have executable, image, script etc files with different extensions. Also, I'm not able to get much help about differentiating between printable ascii file and binary file.

Answer (score 1):

as @claus Ibsen said to filter the files you can use a filefilter property so that you pick only files based on extension and some standard pattern something like this

```
    <bean id="FileFilter" class="org.apache.camel.component.file.AntPathMatcherGenericFileFilter">
    <!--        ?   matches one character
                *   matches zero or more characters
                **  matches zero or more directories in a path -->
    <property name="includes" value="#{databaseProperties.getProperties().getProperty('file.name.pattern')}"/>
    <!-- if you wan to exclude specific files say bad in name or .exe files. Use comma to separate multiple excludes -->
    <!-- <property name="excludes" value="**/*bad*,**/*.exe"/> -->
    </bean>
```

and your file.name.pattern can be something like this   **/contract.csv